# Was the fact that Earth's position is never the same ever addressed in time travel stories?

Tags: time-travel, history-of, space, science-fiction-genre

Everyone familiar with space knows that:

1. the Earth is rotating around itself and moving around the Sun.
2. The Sun is orbiting the center of the Milky Way.
3. The Milky Way is itself moving closer to the Andromeda Galaxy.

So a particular spot in Earth is never at the same place at different times.

But every iteration of time travel I know of states that the time traveler is transported in a position relative to Earth at a given time (if not to the exact same position). In a more scientifically accurate universe, **travelling to the past or the future, but at the same spot should mean you wouldn't end up on Earth surface, but 99,999...% more likely in the big vacuum of space** (if not inside a sun or a black hole, for extra fun). A time-jump of a few minutes would even send you inside Earth ground or up in the air/outside the atmosphere.

**I wonder if this was ever addressed in any time travel story,** like through complex calculations making time travel possible, or the statement that time travel positional is Earth-relative.

Comment: No. No one ever thought of this before. >_>

Comment: This is a common misconception about space. The phrase "Earth's position is never the same" is not correct. When describing any sort of spatial position, you have to also include a reference frame. The Earth's position is never the same, with respect to the Sun/Moon/Solar System/ etc. The Earth is no more rotating around the Sun than the Sun (and everything else) is rotating around the Earth, depending how you choose to show the math. Since time travel is already fanciful, it's not a large stretch to say that the mechanism behind it binds itself to Earth's reference frame.

Comment: It was never officially addressed in the BTTF movies, but this is a fun link that analyses the concept.  Warning for a small amount of bad language https://www.overthinkingit.com/2009/01/16/the-science-of-back-to-the-future/

Comment: It's been addressed by a number of stories, but usually handwaved away with a 'It compensates for the movement of the planet' type comment.  I forget the title, but one Fredric Brown story has time travelers trapped between the ticks of time, and the first guess was exactly what you mentioned, although the scientist then made the disclaimer I mentioned.  For a similar issue (more conservation of momentum, but still) look at Larry Niven's 'stepping discs' to see it in action; it's a plot point in a few stories.

Comment: Yes. Here. https://www.amazon.de/Seeds-Time-English-Kay-Kenyon-ebook/dp/B00SA7GEHS/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1